# Using Two dropboxs to select an individual cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create two dropdowns that after two items are selected, a third cell is selected. Somewhat like a times table, where a dropdown of each number will result in the value of the intersection of the row and column be selected.

I have an example image, where I want to select the row header (A,B,C,D) and the Soil Condition (Good, Fair) and have the resulting number be displayed in I2

[image: example of goal]

How would I go about this in Excel?

Comment: INDEX/MATCH/MATCH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what your looking for. You can enter this formula into the cell you want the end result to be
=INDEX($A$3:$D$4,MATCH(H2,$E$3:$E$4,0),MATCH(G2,$A$2:$D$2,0))
[image]